# python-docx: getting errors that font and styles are not attributes of the Document object

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-docx

I'm new to python and python-docx. I'm trying to create a simple table in a Word document and modify the font in each cell. I've read the documentation. I understand that character-level formatting is applied at the run level, even in tables, and I've attempted to follow what seem like very simple examples. I'm sure I'm missing something but just can't figure it out.

**Here is my simple attempt at using the styles attribute:**

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
styles = document.styles

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-d72c837347db>", line 1, in <module>
styles = document.styles
AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'styles'
```

**Here I'm trying to use the font attribute. This example is straight out of [python-docx.pdf](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-docx/stable/python-docx.pdf):**

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run()
font = run.font

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-7-0f44a2fd03a4>", line 1, in <module>
font = run.font
AttributeError: 'Run' object has no attribute 'font'
```

Is there something else I need to import?

Note: I'm using Python 2.7 in Spyder

Comment: How did you install `python-docx`? Also, check the version with `from docx import __version__; print(__version__)`. You should get '0.8.6'.

Comment: Hi, I installed it using anaconda and thought I did have version 0.8.6 but apparently I have 0.7.4 so I guess that's the problem? Is 0.8.6 available in Python 2.7? I can't use pip to install because my company prohibits software installation. I can only install within anaconda. Thanks so much for your attention.

Comment: @scanny You were absolutely right. I just needed to make sure I had version 0.8.6. Everything works now! Thanks so much!